# Set folder browser dialog start location

Tags: c#

Is there any way to set the initial directory of a folder browser dialog to a non-special folder?  This is what I'm currently using

```
fdbLocation.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
```

but I want to use a path I have stored in a string something like this

```
fdbLocation.RootFolder = myFolder;
```

This causes an error "Cannot convert 'string' to 'System.Environment.SpecialFolder'".

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Just set the `SelectedPath` property before calling `ShowDialog`.

```
fdbLocation.SelectedPath = myFolder;
```

Comment: Note that it's required to set `RootFolder` to `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` or this may not work.

Comment: See Chad Grants answer below:  He rightly explains that the RootFolder must be set, and the SelectedPath must be *below* that RootFolder in order to work.

Comment: This works for me but it doesn't set the focus to the folder. I have to manually scroll down and find the folder it defaulted to. Is there a way to have it set the focus automatically when shown?

Comment: This is however _not_ the same as setting `RootFolder`. If `RootFolder` is set, only the specified folder and any subfolders that are beneath it will appear in the dialog box. `SelectedPath` merely pre-selects the given path.

Answer (score 38):

Set the `SelectedPath` property before you call `ShowDialog` ...

```
folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\temp\";
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Will start them at `C:\Temp`

Comment: Is required to set ***RootFolder***  (`SelectedPath is set to an absolute path that is a subfolder of RootFolder`) ? Behaviour as is: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` returns _C:\Users\Myusername\Desktop._ Using ***Impersonate code*** (with LogonType LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ) returns _empty string_

Answer (score 29):

```
fldrDialog.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

> "If the SelectedPath property is set before showing the dialog box, the folder with this path will be the selected folder, as long as SelectedPath is set to an absolute path that is a subfolder of RootFolder (or more accurately, points to a subfolder of the shell namespace represented by RootFolder)."

[MSDN - SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath.aspx)

> "The GetFolderPath method returns the locations associated with this enumeration. The locations of these folders can have different values on different operating systems, the user can change some of the locations, and the locations are localized."

Re: Desktop vs DesktopDirectory

**Desktop**

> "The logical Desktop rather than the physical file system location."

**DesktopDirectory:**

> "The directory used to physically
>   store file objects on the desktop. Do
>   not confuse this directory with the
>   desktop folder itself, which is a
>   virtual folder."

[MSDN - Special Folder Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

[MSDN - GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx)

Comment: For special paths you can do  {{fldrDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory}}

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.  The key is that the SelectedPath must be below the RootFolder if the dialog is to be pointing to the SelectedPath when it opens.

Comment: Behaviour as is: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` returns _C:\Users\Myusername\Desktop._ Using ***Impersonate code*** (with LogonType LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ) returns _empty string_

Answer (score 9):

To set the directory selected path and the retrieve the new directory:

```
dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.SelectedPath = m_LogDirectory;
if (dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     txtLogDirectory.Text = dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.SelectedPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found on [dotnet-snippets.de](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/folderbrowserdialog-mit-benutzerdefiniertem-root/1738)

With reflection this works and sets the **real RootFolder!**

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class RootFolderBrowserDialog
    {

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///   The description of the dialog.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description { get; set; } = "Chose folder...";

        /// <summary>
        ///   The ROOT path!
        /// </summary>
        public string RootPath { get; set; } = "";

        /// <summary>
        ///   The SelectedPath. Here is no initialization possible.
        /// </summary>
        public string SelectedPath { get; private set; } = "";

        #endregion Public Properties

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///   Shows the dialog...
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>OK, if the user selected a folder or Cancel, if no folder is selected.</returns>
        public DialogResult ShowDialog()
        {
            var shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
            var shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);
            var folder = shellType.InvokeMember(
                             "BrowseForFolder", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                             shell, new object[] { 0, Description, 0, RootPath, });
            if (folder is null)
            {
                return DialogResult.Cancel;
            }
            else
            {
                var folderSelf = folder.GetType().InvokeMember(
                                     "Self", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                                     folder, null);
                SelectedPath = folderSelf.GetType().InvokeMember(
                                   "Path", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                                   folderSelf, null) as string;
                // maybe ensure that SelectedPath is set
                return DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to expand and collapse the preset folder item ?

Comment: i upvoted and like this answer, but!! it should be noted that the user will not be able to browse higher than what this root folder is set to, according to msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-browseforfolder . The work around i used is simple, use the default .net FolderBrowser, set the special folder to MyComputer, then set the selected path. this will also expand the folders upto the selected path directory, but will NOT scroll to it.

Comment: Perfect! - At first it did not work because I had '/' instead of '\' in RootPath.

Comment: @David - Maybe the `set` of "RootPath" should be changed, so that "/" is changed to "\". (At moment I work in a mixed environment Linux/Windows, there this is a must)

Answer (score 3):

**FOR THOSE FIGHTING WITH THIS..**

There is a hidden feature that affects how the dialog behaves.

When you enter directory **path without trailing \**, for example c:\temp\abc, then the dialog opens in c:\temp and abc is written in Folder, so it's basically selected but you are in parent folder

When you enter directory **path with trailing \**, for example c:\temp\abc, then it actually opens c:\temp\abc folder so you are inside it.

**dialog.RootFolder does NOT need** to be set for this to work.. At least on my computer with .NET 5

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an accidental double escaping.

this works:

```
SelectedPath = @"C:\Program Files\My Company\My product";
```

this doesn't:

```
SelectedPath = @"C:\\Program Files\\My Company\\My product";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and you don't need reflection. You have to set the SelectedPath property to desired folder but, because SelectedPath is ONLY set to an absolute path that is a subfolder of RootFolder before, you have to set the RootFolder. For example:

Your initial folder is a Desktop subfolder:

```
dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory;
dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.SelectedPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "yourDesktopFolder");
```

Your initial folder is a normal folder (so is a My Computer subfolder):

```
dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
dlgBrowseForLogDirectory.SelectedPath = @"e:\yourFolder";
```

Have nice coding,
Claudio