# FolderBrowserDialog add Custom Root Name

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

```
FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
fd.RootFolder = string.Format("D:\\Project\\folder1\\folder2\\ Results\\{0}", FolderName);
```

in FolderBrowserDialog the Rootfolder Expects a type of environment.specialfolder
but i want to add my folder as root folder.
i dont want to set the SelectedPath as my custom path. 
is there any way to do so.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not use fd.SelectedPath?

Comment: @ataraxia why not? i can use anything but read my question carefully . selectedfolder property will save the default custom path but what i mentioned is something like this- whenever i open this folderbrowserdialog the opened location should be my custom path . setting the selectedfolder will not help in this situation.

Comment: @ataraxia - Yep.. same here.

Comment: If you set SelectedPath to your “root folder” every time just before you open your browser, the browser will open at that location. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @user1074069  here is my code   FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog(); 
            fd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;   
            fd.SelectedPath = string.Format("D:\\Project\\folder\\nextfolder\\nextfolder\\{0}", FolderName); 
            DialogResult result = fd.ShowDialog();   but the folderbrowser is opening at the rootpath location .

Comment: What is your string.Format function doing and why? If that function is producing a string of a folder that doesn't exist and you then try to set the SelectedPath as that folder (which doesn't exist) then the dialog will default to the root folder instead. Check what the output of string.Format("D:\\Project\\folder1\\folder2\\ Results\\{0}", FolderName) is

Comment: @ataraxia read my latest comment is that what u r talking about.

Comment: @yashpalkhatri no you've just reposted your code, read my comment again and check what the *actual* output of your string.Format function is, it may be producing an invalid folder string. Check what the variable "FolderString" is and also remove the space from "...\\ Results\\..."

Comment: @yashpalkhatri What happens when you run your code as you posted in your comment? If the browser pops up showing your Desktop (for example) rather than your expected folder, than, as ataraxia, says, your string doesn’t point to a real folder.

Comment: @user1074069 it will open the RootFolder as the SelectedPath is not valid, therefore the RootFolder **must** be a Environment.SpecialFolder because that **will definitely exist**

Comment: @ataraxia thanks your solution worked for me .yes string.format()  is producing a string of a folder that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ataraxia Yes, understood... was trying to be brief. My point was that, as you say, his code snippet should work for him if his string points to a valid folder. I do it all the time while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the `RootFolder` to a custom folder because this is used as a fallback, which I think is what's happening in your code. .Net **knows** that special folders exist, whereas your custom directory may not.

It looks like you need to remove the space in here `...folder2\\ Results\\...` and/or check the `FolderName` variable as this is producing a directory string that doesn't exist, therefore your dialog is using the `RootFolder` instead.

Comment: I edited the folder name before posting the question here that's why one space is there . The actual problem was with the folder itself because if we add any folder location to Selectedpath that doesn't exist it will set the rootname as the specified rootname itself or the default one(if not specified)  not with the selectedPath. Thanks for your suggestion of checking the folder existence .

Answer (score 0):

1. Default the RootFolder to Desktop
2. Set your custom folder as the SelectedPath property

   fd.SelectedPath = string.Format("D:\Project\folder1\folder2\ Results\{0}", FolderName);
3. Call Show method of dialog

   fd.ShowDialog();

Note that order of these settings need to be preserved, else will lead to wrong result.

More detail in following answered question
[Set folder browser dialog start location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844423/set-folder-browser-dialog-start-location)

Comment: in this situation the dialog box will only show the desktop path but what i want is  to redirect this FolderBrowserDialog  to my custom location .in your Solution the selectedfolder will save our custom path if we do not select any path.

Answer (score 0):

I've dropped a folder browser on a form called "folderBrowserDialog1" and the below seems to work. The special folder option is simply an option to allow the browsing to start in a "Special" folder. E.g. Windows etc.. and it provides a neat mechanism to set it without typing the full path. If you need a custom path, then set the SelectedPath property.

```
folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
//The above is optional. You don't need to set it.

folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"C:\"; //Your path here
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem .i want to open my custom path directly whenever this function gets a call. but your answer is suggesting me to set the default selected path.

Comment: note that root folder and selected path are completely different.

Comment: @yashpalkhatri - Yes i know they are completely different, as per my answer. Try setting the Selected Path to a folder and see what happens!

Comment: "try setting the selected path to a folder" will only set the default path i.e. if we do not select any folder this will be our selected folder but what i want is someting like this whenever i open this folderbrowserdialog the opened location should be my custom path . setting the selectedfolder will not help in this situation.